# Getting per average of timestamp data in R

Tags: r, time, timestamp, average

I have SCADA data from different sensor which are recorded at and when the value changes.
I have tried some but being new in R, I am not able to debug error.
How to change this value changing data as per minute average data....
here is sample data:

```
Date        Time    Value
01-02-2017  06:47:04    9
01-02-2017  06:47:16    10
01-02-2017  06:47:40    11
01-02-2017  06:48:04    9
01-02-2017  06:48:16    12
01-02-2017  06:48:40    10
01-02-2017  06:48:52    11
01-02-2017  06:49:04    13
01-02-2017  06:49:16    11
01-02-2017  06:49:28    14
01-02-2017  06:50:04    15
```

I want to calculate per minute average of value 
it should consider value like:

```
Time    Value
06:48:00    11
06:48:01    11
06:48:02    11
06:48:03    11
06:48:04    9
06:48:05    9
06:48:06    9
06:48:07    9
06:48:08    9
06:48:09    9
06:48:10    9
06:48:11    9
06:48:12    9
06:48:13    9
06:48:14    9
06:48:15    9
06:48:16    12
06:48:17    12
06:48:18    12
06:48:19    12
06:48:20    12
06:48:21    12
06:48:22    12
06:48:23    12
06:48:24    12
06:48:25    12
06:48:26    12
06:48:27    12
06:48:28    12
06:48:29    12
06:48:30    12
06:48:31    12
06:48:32    12
06:48:33    12
06:48:34    12
06:48:35    12
06:48:36    12
06:48:37    12
06:48:38    12
06:48:39    12
06:48:40    10
06:48:41    10
06:48:42    10
06:48:43    10
06:48:44    10
06:48:45    10
06:48:46    10
06:48:47    10
06:48:48    10
06:48:49    10
06:48:50    10
06:48:51    10
06:48:52    11
06:48:53    11
06:48:54    11
06:48:55    11
06:48:56    11
06:48:57    11
06:48:58    11
06:48:59    11
```

and average for 48th minute would be 10.8.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your Time column is a character vector, you can use the `dplyr` and `lubridate` packages to accomplish the task. Here `df` is your data frame with columns Date, Time, and Value:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(Time = hms(Time)) %>%
  group_by(h = hour(Time), m = minute(Time)) %>%
  summarise(Mean = mean(Value))
```